# How can I update/add new information to my local JSOn file in Flutter? (without creating any classes)

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I made a small application, sort of like a library app where you can add books you've read. So, I have a local JSON file, which looks like this:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows",
    "author": "J.K. Rowling",
    "rating": "4.5",
    "category": "Fantasy",
    "url": "some url"
  },
  {
    "name": "For Whom The Bell Tolls",
    "author": "E. Hemingway",
    "rating": "4",
    "category": "Novel",
    "url": "some url#2"
  }
]
```

In my main.dart file I have a function that reads my JSON file, decodes and loads it in a list named "data":

```dart
readData(){
    DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/books.json").then((s){
      setState(() {
        data = json.decode(s);
      });

    });
  }

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    readData();

  }
```

I can easily add new books to "data" and everything is fine except for one thing, - I don't know how to update/write information to JSON, so the app could show me the updated list with the new book after a restart. I've added. How do I do this? And what should I write into the JSON file, - the updated List with all books or just a Map with a new book?

**Answer to NelsonThiago**

This code is in "class AddingPageState extends  State":

```
Future<String> get _localPath async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }
  Future<File> get _localFile async {
    final path = await _localPath;
    return File('$path/books.json');
  }
  Future<File> writeData(List list) async { // "list" is the updated book-list
    final file = await _localFile;
    String encodedData = jsonEncode(list);
    return file.writeAsString('$encodedData');
  }
```

And I call "writeData" in onPressed function.

Comment: Still getting the ```no such directory/file``` error ??

Comment: No, it just doesnt write/save data in JSON file. I don't get any error, the new book just disappears after I restart my app

Comment: So, basically my app works like this:
1) On the first page I read my JSON file in `initState()` and display the books with all information;
2) Also there's a `floatingActonButton` with `onPressed()` function which navigates a user to the second page and expects a `Map` with an information about a new book (something like `final _newBookInfo = await Navigator,push()`...).
3) On the second page there're fields for information, and a Confirm button. When you press it, it creates a new `Map`, calls `writeData` function and goes back to first page.

Comment: 4) Then there's a function that adds `newBook` info to `List` of all books and displays them all. 

The problem is that when I restart the app, it shows me the old list without a new book. Apparently, the `writeData` function doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make this using a local NoSql database like [sembast](https://pub.dev/packages/sembast), this way you could add, delete and update your data. But as you are already working with json, You just need to encode your new changed `data` to json and write to the file again.
To write and read files, instead of using `rootBundle` read this [read and write files](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files).

Comment: I've tried the code from FlutterDev's article before, and I got errors like "no such directory/file"

Comment: Can you show the code trying to access device directory?

Comment: I added the answer to my post

Comment: Answered to the question under the post.

Comment: Yes I can see, I just can see why it would not work if everything looks fine, you should look for errors or print the data to see what's happening.

Comment: cuz in the article there's a function `_incrementCounter()` and it is `Future<File>`, so it returns `return widget.storage.writeCounter(_counter)`, maybe its smth related to this? or maybe i should make a new class `Storage`, just like in the documentation

Comment: yeah, i created a class just like in docs, and it still doesnt save data in JSON file.

Comment: should I just forget about this and use Firebase instead?

Comment: Firebase is a good backend option for app development, but as you are trying to save data locally, you should learn how to use local databases like sembast or sqflite.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your JSON file, you are storing the Books as a list of JSON objects, which will make things easier.

But your request of solving this without adding new classes is a bit strange because adding a Book class in your case would make things much easier.

So I am going to give you a solution that assumes that you create a new Book class.

1. Start by reading the file as you are currently doing.
2. Store the content of the file in a List of dynamic List.
3. Iterate through the list using the map function, add using the from JSON function in the Book class decode the JSON to a book object, then apply the toList() function on that map.
4. Return the result to your UI and treat it as any other list.
5. When you want to add a new Book, create a new object of the book class and add it to your list.
6. When the user finishes adding, transform the list to a JSON object agian and store it in the file again;

Something like this:

```
The Book Class:

class Book {
  String? name;
  String? author;
  String? rating;
  String? category;
  String? url;

  Book({
    required this.name,
    required this.author,
   required this.rating,
  required  this.category,
    required this.url,
  });

  Book.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    author = json['author'];
    rating = json['rating'];
    category = json['category'];
    url = json['url'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['author'] = this.author;
    data['rating'] = this.rating;
    data['category'] = this.category;
    data['url'] = this.url;
    return data;
  }
  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'Book(name: $name, author: $author, rating: $rating, category: $category, url: $url)';
  }
}
```

And main function

```
void main() {
  /// read the file the way you like
  List<dynamic> list = [
    {
      "name": "Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows",
      "author": "J.K. Rowling",
      "rating": "4.5",
      "category": "Fantasy",
      "url": "some url"
    },
    {
      "name": "For Whom The Bell Tolls",
      "author": "E. Hemingway",
      "rating": "4",
      "category": "Novel",
      "url": "some url#2"
    }
  ];

  List<Book> books = list
      .map(
        (jsonObject) => Book.fromJson(jsonObject),
      )
      .toList();

  print(books);

  Book newBook = Book(
      name: 'Some Book',
      author: 'Some Author',
      rating: 'Some rating',
      category: 'Some category',
      url: 'Some Url');

  books.add(newBook);

  print(books);

  books
      .map(
        (book) => book.toJson(),
      )
      .toList();
  
  //Write the the file again to storage or anywhere else 
}
```

Comment: Could you please comment your code and tell me what should I do first, because I'm new coding and I don't really understand classes.

Comment: also I get "Non-nullable instance field "name" must be initialized" errors (same with "author", category" and others). Where in code I can initialize them?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I should have enabled null safety on dart pad !! I will update the answer.
But as advice check out this video about null safety as it becomes the default in flutter projects
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdKwuHQvArY)

Comment: And for the classes topic, I suggest reading and searching about it online as It a fundamental in programming in general.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to know how do I write the updated book list back to JSON file. Because, when I restart the app it just doesnt show me the list with a new book. 


I guess, "toJson" method returns the encoded book-list, but It doesn't seem to save it in my local JSON file.

Comment: basically, all i need is write my list to local JSON file, so i could load it with a new book after i restart the app.

Answer (score 0):

See the following example. But it requires to create a class. The sample **json** file is like below (pretty much similar to your json file) -

```
[
  {"name":"Ash","age":"22","hobby":"golf"},
  {"name":"philip","age":"17","hobby":"fishing"},
  {"name":"charles","age":"32","hobby":"drawing"},
]
```

And I am editing the above code answered by **Ward Suleiman** so that you can read from a local json file and write to it-

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';

List<Player> players = [];

void main() async{
    print("hello world");
    final File file = File('D:/Sadi/.../test.json'); //load the json file
    await readPlayerData(file); //read data from json file
    
    Player newPlayer = Player(  //add a new item to data list
      'Samy Brook',
      '31',
      'cooking'
      );

  players.add(newPlayer);

  print(players.length);

  players  //convert list data  to json 
      .map(
        (player) => player.toJson(),
      )
      .toList();
      
    file.writeAsStringSync(json.encode(players));  //write (the whole list) to json file
}

Future<void> readPlayerData (File file) async { 
  
    
    String contents = await file.readAsString();
    var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(contents);
    
    for(var p in jsonResponse){
        
        Player player = Player(p['name'],p['age'],p['hobby']);
        players.add(player);
    }
    
      
}
```

And the Player class -

```
class Player {
  late String name;
  late String age;
  late String hobby;
  

  Player(
     this.name,
     this.age,
    this.hobby,
  
  );

  Player.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
    age = json['age'];
    hobby = json['hobby'];
    
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['age'] = this.age;
    data['hobby'] = this.hobby;
    
    return data;
  }
  
}
```